# how to make dropdown active in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown menu, and i am trying to provide an active state upon click. Now this works when the user clicks the link, the active class is added and no problems occur. The problem is removing the active class when clicking another a tag. If you click the same a tag the class is removed but if you click another a tag you get the following occurrence.

I only want one link to be active at all times

[image]

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).click(function () {
        $('.link.activeLink').removeClass('activeLink')
    });

    $('.link').click(function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('activeLink');

        if ($(e.parentNode).hasClass('show')) {
            $('.activeLink').removeClass('activeLink');
        } 
    });

});
```

html:

```
  <li class="nav-item dropdown px-2 arrowDown">
                    <a class="nav-link link dropdown-toggle text-white paddingRightButton h-100 noPaddingRightLeft" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="flatRoofingDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Flat Roofing
                    </a>
```

Updated screen grab :

[image]

as you can see the dropdown has closed but the link remains active this is behaviour i dont want.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep only one link active at all time by removing the class`.active` from every element with the class `.link` before toggling the class `.active` on the currently clicked `.link`. Note that it's also necessary to call [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) when a link is clicked to stop the click event from bubbling up to the `$(document).click()` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
      $('.link.activeLink').removeClass('activeLink')
    });

    $('.link').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('.link.activeLink').removeClass('activeLink')
      $(this).toggleClass('activeLink');
    });
});
```

```css
.activeLink {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown px-2 arrowDown">
    <a class="nav-link link dropdown-toggle text-white paddingRightButton h-100 noPaddingRightLeft" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="flatRoofingDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Flat Roofing
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown px-2 arrowDown">
    <a class="nav-link link dropdown-toggle text-white paddingRightButton h-100 noPaddingRightLeft" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="flatRoofingDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Concrete Roof Tiles
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This would work however if you clicked the same link you run into a problem. The active state would always remain. For example you click the dropdown link that link becomes active but you then click to close the dropdown menu but the link still remains active. i have provided a screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

so this was the solution

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        $('.link.activeLink').removeClass('activeLink')
    });

    $('.link').click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('activeLink')) {
            $(this).removeClass('activeLink');
        } else {
            $('.link.activeLink').removeClass('activeLink')
            $(this).toggleClass('activeLink');
        }         
    });
});
```